# How to configure logging in JBOSS EAP 6.3 / AS 7 by .war name

Tags: java, jboss

What is the new strategy to configure JBoss EAP 6.3 / AS 7 with deployment specific settings, but without modifying the .war/.ear?  (By modifying the deployment file you could do it by including a logging properties file or by specifying a logging profile in the manifest).

It was previously possible to use a filter "org.jboss.logging.filter.TCLFilter"
[Separating application logs on jboss 4.0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854902/separating-application-logs-on-jboss-4-0-5), up until JBoss AS 6.0.0.M1.

However - "Starting with JBoss AS 6.0.0.M2 the ability to log to separate log files, per application, will be implemented in a different way. The TCLFilter/TCLMCFilter will *not* apply " From this article: 
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SeparatingApplicationLogs. 
Sadly, they never updated the article with the new style of configuration.

Is there a good way to do this in AS 7 / EAP 6.3? Or is my only option to include a logging profile, or logging properties file in the deployment artifact?

Using logging categories doesn't work because there are shared packages between deployments that I need to log to different files.

I'm running in standalone mode, with a fairly simple logging subsystem configuration currently.

```
      <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
      </root-logger>
      <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c (%M:%L)  - %m%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%5p %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c (%M:%L)  - %m%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```